# Fixing failed Bootcamp partition using Diskutils

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I tried to create a bootcamp partition using the Bootcamp assistant, however when it should have booted into Windows to continue the installation, it failed and ended up taking the majority (>40GB) into the abyss. I've since decided just to run Parallels for the time being, but I'm running on only a fraction of my drive space and I cannot recover the partition or see it in the normal disk management tool. In the normal tool, it shows the drive is 121GB but MacOS can only use 68GB of that with the rest invisible.

I first tried fsdisk in the recovery command prompt, to no avail. Next I went to terminal. I know the failed partition is in here, but I'm uncomfortable removing anything as I don't have the experience.

Here's the output of *diskutil list*:

```
    /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         68.0 GB    disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +68.0 GB    disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            61.5 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 23.3 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                519.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data Backup                  1000.0 GB  disk2s2
```

Here's the output of *disktutil info disk1*:

```
   Device Identifier:        disk1
   Device Node:              /dev/disk1
   Whole:                    Yes
   Part of Whole:            disk1
   Device / Media Name:      APPLE SSD SM0128G

   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:              None

   Content (IOContent):      EF57347C-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 PCI
   SMART Status:             Verified
   Disk / Partition UUID:    9F300D98-E7ED-44EC-AF87-706495D5D6CB

   Disk Size:                68.0 GB (68000133120 Bytes) (exactly 132812760 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:          Internal
   Removable Media:          Fixed

   Solid State:              Yes
   Virtual:                  Yes
   Hardware AES Support:     No
```

Here's the output of *diskutil info disk0*:

```
   Device Identifier:        disk0
   Device Node:              /dev/disk0
   Whole:                    Yes
   Part of Whole:            disk0
   Device / Media Name:      APPLE SSD SM0128G

   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:              None

   Content (IOContent):      GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 PCI
   SMART Status:             Verified

   Disk Size:                121.3 GB (121332826112 Bytes) (exactly 236978176 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:          Internal
   Removable Media:          Fixed

   Solid State:              Yes
   Virtual:                  No
   Hardware AES Support:     No
```

Finally, the output of *diskutil apfs list*:

```
APFS Container (1 found)
|
+-- Container disk1 9F300D98-E7ED-44EC-AF87-706495D5D6CB
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk1
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      68000133120 B (68.0 GB)
    Minimum Size:                 65509048320 B (65.5 GB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   63281377280 B (63.3 GB) (93.1% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       4718755840 B (4.7 GB) (6.9% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk0s2 82977036-F65B-4377-8D6C-833A7CB52DA0
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2
    |   Size:                       68000133120 B (68.0 GB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s1 136901F2-6597-37E8-816B-8DBC0F223C18
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s1 (No specific role)
    |   Name:                      Macintosh HD (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /
    |   Capacity Consumed:         61543849984 B (61.5 GB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s2 033F3AF2-BD86-4F1F-811E-EE6DCB71B51F
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s2 (Preboot)
    |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         23252992 B (23.3 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s3 F23EC2A3-2305-46DA-9508-8393695AA97F
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s3 (Recovery)
    |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         519036928 B (519.0 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s4 4CF8D2E3-2889-4AC1-87E4-F3E62BE7C949
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s4 (VM)
        Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               /private/var/vm
        Capacity Consumed:         1073762304 B (1.1 GB)
        FileVault:                 No
```

So it looks like disk1 is what I need to keep, the MacOS install and all the space I'm using. FYI disk2 is a mounted external hard drive unrelated to this issue.

What commands should I run to fix?

Edit:
Output of *diskutil info disk0s1*:

```
    Device Identifier:        disk0s1
    Device Node:              /dev/disk0s1
    Whole:                    No
    Part of Whole:            disk0

    Volume Name:              EFI
    Mounted:                  No

    Partition Type:           EFI
    File System Personality:  MS-DOS FAT32
    Type (Bundle):            msdos
    Name (User Visible):      MS-DOS (FAT32)

    OS Can Be Installed:      No
    Media Type:               Generic
    Protocol:                 PCI
    SMART Status:             Verified
    Volume UUID:              0E239BC6-F960-3107-89CF-1C97F78BB46B
    Disk / Partition UUID:    002E8AA2-DA49-4D79-973E-937E0C65966A
    Partition Offset:         20480 Bytes (40 512-Byte-Device-Blocks)

    Disk Size:                209.7 MB (209715200 Bytes) (exactly 409600 512-Byte-Units)
    Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

    Volume Total Space:       0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)
    Volume Free Space:        0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)

    Read-Only Media:          No
    Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (not mounted)

    Device Location:          Internal
    Removable Media:          Fixed

    Solid State:              Yes
    Hardware AES Support:     No
```

And the output of *diskutil info disk1s1*:

```
    Device Identifier:        disk1s1
    Device Node:              /dev/disk1s1
    Whole:                    No
    Part of Whole:            disk1

    Volume Name:              Macintosh HD
    Mounted:                  Yes
    Mount Point:              /

    Partition Type:           41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
    File System Personality:  APFS
    Type (Bundle):            apfs
    Name (User Visible):      APFS
    Owners:                   Enabled

    OS Can Be Installed:      Yes
    Booter Disk:              disk1s2
    Recovery Disk:            disk1s3
    Media Type:               Generic
    Protocol:                 PCI
    SMART Status:             Verified
    Volume UUID:              136901F2-6597-37E8-816B-8DBC0F223C18
    Disk / Partition UUID:    136901F2-6597-37E8-816B-8DBC0F223C18

    Disk Size:                68.0 GB (68000133120 Bytes) (exactly 132812760 512-Byte-Units)
    Device Block Size:        4096 Bytes

    Volume Total Space:       68.0 GB (68000133120 Bytes) (exactly 132812760 512-Byte-Units)
    Volume Used Space:        58.5 GB (58498363392 Bytes) (exactly 114254616 512-Byte-Units) (86.0%)
    Volume Free Space:        9.5 GB (9501769728 Bytes) (exactly 18558144 512-Byte-Units) (14.0%)
    Allocation Block Size:    4096 Bytes

    Read-Only Media:          No
    Read-Only Volume:         No

    Device Location:          Internal
    Removable Media:          Fixed

    Solid State:              Yes
    Hardware AES Support:     No
```

Comment: If you want to know where the missing space is, then you will need to add the output from `diskutil info disk0s1` and `diskutil info disk0s2` to your question.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Edited as requested!

Comment: Yes, but I asked for `disk0s2` and you posted `disk1s1`.

Comment: Most likely the command you need to enter is `sudo diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0`.